# LINQ select query always resulting in true value

Tags: c#, linq

When I hit the following line, I always receive a true, regardless of whether "local" appears in the joining `Roles` table.

```
if (objUserRoles.Select(x => (x.Role.Role1 == "local")).Count() > 0)
```

Is my syntax correct?

Comment: Looks fine, but avoid `.Count() > 0` in favour of `.Any()`. The format enumerates the whole list, the latter exits as soon as one result is found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is `Where`:

```
if (objUserRoles.Where(x => x.Role.Role1 == "local").Count() > 0)
```

Or with `Any` it's even better (and performant because in most of the cases it won't iterate trough the whole collection like `Count()`)

```
 if (objUserRoles.Any(x => x.Role.Role1 == "local"))
```

Comment: +1 for noticing the main error (I didn't!), but still, use `any` over `Count() > 0`

Comment: Why will it not iterate over? It does not iterate over when there is no predicate defined like `.Any()`. In your case its `Any(x => x.Role.Role1 == "local"))`. Lambda Variable is defined so it will iterate over.

Comment: No, it will stop after the first item where `x.Role.Role1 == "local"` on the other hand `Count()` will always iterate through the whole collection. But your are right if there is no suitable item or it is the last it will iterate through the collection.

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for:

```
if (objUserRoles.Any(x => x.Role.Role1 == "local"))
```

What you're doing is selecting a series of `bool`s.  E.g. if you had 3 items for which your query returned `false, true, false`, the expression you had asked for that `false, true, false` sequence, not just the object at the location where it was true.  It looks like you're trying to select the values where that series of bools was true, which means you should've used `Where` instead of `Select`.  However, since all you're really doing with that `Where` and `Count` is checking for at least one, you should do `Any`, which does that much more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

**Use [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) Extension Method**

It checks for condition

```
if (objUserRoles.Where(x => (x.Role.Role1 == "local")).Count() > 0)
```

OR

**[Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) Extension Method**

```
if (objUserRoles.Any(x => x.Role.Role1 == "local"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use .Where(expr) instead of .Select(expr).

Answer (score 1):

it is better with a `Any`

```
if (objUserRoles.Where(x => (x.Role.Role1 == "local")).Any())
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, .Any() or .Where().Count() will give you what you're looking for.  Your code of...

```
if (objUserRoles.Select(x => (x.Role.Role1 == "local")).Count() > 0)
```

... is actually creating an `IEnumerable<bool>` where each item is true/false based on `x.Role.Role1 == "local"`.  Your final result was always true because the `.Count()` of your `IEnumerable<bool>` will always be greater than 0 unless your objUserRoles collection actually contains 0 elements.

Hope that clarification makes sense for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

well, your are not statement transforms anything in your `objUserRoles` to a `boolean`, so the result set of the

```
objUserRoles.Select(x => (x.Role.Role1 == "local"))
```

is a `IEnumerable<bool>` with as many elements of your `objUserRoles` collection.
i guess what you want to do is described by the following query

```
if (objUserRoles.Where(x => x.Role.Role1 == "local").Count() > 0)
```

or even better

```
if (objUserRoles.Any(x => x.Role.Role1 == "local"))
```